# Zune software and Podcast management

Tags: podcasts, windows-phone, zune-software

Is there anyone out there that has played enough with Zune software to know how it manages podcasts? In particular, how do get the Zune software to delete podcasts that have been listened to?

What I'd ideally like is for the Zune software automatically to delete podcasts after they've been listened to. I'd like it to keep all unplayed podcasts until I marked them as listened to (no arbitrary limit to the number of unplayed podcasts).

To complicate things, I'm not actually using the Zune software to subscribe to the podcasts (because the WP7 devices don't support highspeed playback of podcasts). So I'm using Juice to download the podcasts and automatically process the downloads with Sox to speed them up. The resulting files are in a podcast folder monitored by Zune so they get imported automatically. These are then synced to my WP7 phone so I can listen to them (what a ridiculous amount of work to be able to do what my old iPhone could do easily). After I listen to them, the next sync will mark the podcasts as played in the Zune software and remove them from the phone. Now I just need to figure out how to get the Zune software to delete the played podcasts from the computer so they don't just keep collecting up. Manually deleting the podcast on the phone doesn't cause the Zune software to delete the file (it doesn't even mark it as played).

Comment: In a word, as much as I love the Zune software, you can't do that with it, I'm afraid. The settings for a series are based entirely on the number of episodes. You have more flexibility when it comes to synchronization, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears they age out of the library based on the series settings that says "Keep x episodes of this podcast."

The telling thing is the next line that says "Episodes you add to your collection aren't affected by this setting"

The way I read that is: if the Zune software doesn't download it, it will not delete it.

Comment: Is that "the last x episodes" or "last x unplayed episodes" or something else? I hate the lack of documentation for the Zune software. <sigh>

Comment: "last x episodes is what it says in my software.  Have you tried any of the Zune specific forums?